# Does anyone know the instructions for building a hyperledger fabric network from scratch step by step?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm a novice in fabric development and I am at the beginning of the road. I could not find a suitable integrated tutorial from the base, so i follow hyperledger fabric from latest version documents. From Here I understood a number of concepts such as working with the test network, the commercial paper network, how to work with and develop smart contracts and ... . But I'm a little confused. The fabric document is not coherent and step by step and I could not figure out how to write my target network from scratch (like config my own network, write yaml file and scripts), so does anyone know the instructions for building a hyperledger fabric network from scratch step by step?

Comment: This repo might help you https://github.com/shamonshan/fabric-basic I was created this long time back

Comment: Have you read through https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deployment_guide_overview.html